# Postgresql citext datatype unique constraint fail

Tags: postgresql, case-sensitive, citext

I need to create a unique constraint on citext column, but it fails. 
Here is the example:

```
create table test (name citext);

ALTER TABLE ONLY test
    ADD CONSTRAINT test_name_uq UNIQUE (name);

  insert into test(name) values ('SIMIT'); --succeded.

  insert into test(name) values ('SİMİT'); --failed
```

Here is the error code:

> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test_name_uq"
>   DETAIL:  Key (name)=(SİMİT) already exists. SQL state: 23505

SIMIT and SİMİT is not the same thing. It should not return an error. 
I don't want to add any upper or lower function in my code. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What are the `lc_ctype` of the database and the operating system?

Comment: When I run "SHOW client_encoding;" it returns "'UNICODE" , my database is Amazon RDS Postgresql, that's why I don't know my OS.

Comment: `show lc_ctype` ?

Comment: It returns error 'ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "lc_type"
SQL state: 42704'

Comment: It's not `lc_type` but `lc_ctype`. This is what drives the behavior of `lower()` and by extension `citext`.

Comment: I'm sorry. When I run "SHOW lc_ctype;" it returns "en_US.UTF-8"